# 'ProductNumber'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a few questions I don't have any experience in a SQL, so my questions will looks funny to some experts here (-:
I want to run some checks in my production SQL.
I have a few databases and I want to check some things.
first, I want to check the index so I found this Query on this great website:

```
SELECT
     t.name  TableName,
     col.name ColumnName,
     ind.name IndexName
FROM
     sys.indexes ind
INNER JOIN`enter code here`
     sys.index_columns ic ON  ind.object_id = ic.object_id and ind.index_id = ic.index_id
INNER JOIN
     sys.columns col ON ic.object_id = col.object_id and ic.column_id = col.column_id
INNER JOIN
     sys.tables t ON ind.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE
     (ind.is_primary_key = 0
     AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0)
ORDER BY
     t.name, col.name, ind.name
```

I don't know how to find t.name or col.name

I have found this Query that can find all the miss details

```
select * from information_schema.columns where column_name = 'ProductNumber'
```

But I dont know how to find the `'ProductNumber'`

Last one, if I want to change the Snapshot Mode to ON it will ask to restart the server or it will have any impact on some running session or transaction and make any data corruption?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Those sys-tables are product specific.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `col.name like '%ProductNumber%'` in where condition

```
SELECT
     t.name  TableName,
     col.name ColumnName,
     ind.name IndexName
FROM
     sys.indexes ind
INNER JOIN`enter code here`
     sys.index_columns ic ON  ind.object_id = ic.object_id and ind.index_id = ic.index_id
INNER JOIN
     sys.columns col ON ic.object_id = col.object_id and ic.column_id = col.column_id
INNER JOIN
     sys.tables t ON ind.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE
     ind.is_primary_key = 0
     AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0 and col.name like '%ProductNumber%'
ORDER BY
     t.name, col.name, ind.name
```

Comment: Hi, tnx for answering.

but I need help how to find, where is the t.name or col.name details run the index check.